# How to fetch all available wifi list in ios SDK and how to change wifi Login through app?

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi

I first want to tell you that I have gone through a number of questions and blog telling that we can't find the `list of all available wifi from iPhone app` apart from a jail broken device.

I have gone through an app recently called **Wemo** and there I can see that they are fetching all the available wifi list and ask for password.When I enter the password then it changes the device wifi through the application which I have selected.The app is also present in the App Store.How is it doing that if we don't have permission to access any of the available wifi and also how it is changing the wifi login of the device from the application.Is there anything I am missing?